# How to declare any type to a module introduced by a relative path ？

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

In the `index.ts` of the `src/pkg` dir, I introduced a module by `import Component from './Component'`, which is a vue component, I want to declare it as any type.

So I created a `Component.d.ts` file, which content is just `const m:any;export default m;`. But when I run `tsc` and emit output, I found that the `types` folder containing the '.d.ts' file created by 'tsc' does not contain `Component.d.ts`, therefore Typescript report a problem about `Cannot find module './Component' or its corresponding type declarations.` in `types/index.d.ts`.

But I have no idea how to solve this problem. I want to know how to correctly declare this vue component as any type and the `.d.ts` files in the generated `types` can be correctly parsed by typescript or if I made any mistakes during the above process.

Thanks!

This is an online address for explaining the file structure:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-miuhcr?file=tsconfig.json

And this is my local situation after exec `tsc`

[image]